# GNU ARM assembler giving a seemingly irrelevant register in error message

Tags: c, assembly, arm, gnu, inline-assembly

#### Goal

I'm building a mutex primitive using gcc inline assembly for a CortexM7 target using the LDREX and STREX instructions, following the [Barrier Litmus Tests and Cookbook](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/genc007826/latest) document from ARM.

#### Code

```
static inline void testAcquireLock(unsigned int *lock) {
  unsigned int tempStore1 = 0;
  unsigned int tempStore2 = 0;

  __asm__ volatile(
      "Loop%=:                         \n\t" // "%=" generates unique #
      "LDREX %[ts1], %[lock]           \n\t" // exclusive read lock
      "CMP %[ts1], #0                  \n\t" // check if 0
      "ITT EQ                          \n\t" // block for below conds.
      "STREXEQ %[ts1], %[ts2], %[lock] \n\t" // attempt to ex. store new value
      "CMPEQ %[ts1], #0                \n\t" // test if store suceeded
      "BNE Loop%=                      \n\t" // retry if not
      "DMB                             \n\t" // mem barrier for subsequent reads
      : [lock] "+l"(*lock), [ts1] "=l"(tempStore1), [ts2] "=l"(tempStore2)
      : // inputs
      : "memory");
}
```

#### Error Message

The only error shown is below. The assembler is referencing R15, which doesn't seem to be used in the generated assembly? Line 191 in the error message corresponds to the first `LDREX` instruction seen above.

```
[build] /tmp/ccEU4dXd.s: Assembler messages:
[build] /tmp/ccEU4dXd.s:191: Error: r15 not allowed here -- `ldrex r1,r3'
[build] /tmp/ccEU4dXd.s:194: Error: r15 not allowed here -- `strexeq r1,r2,r3'
```

#### Build/Compiler Options

The project is configured with CMake using the following compiler settings:

```
target_compile_options(testing
PRIVATE
    -mcpu=cortex-m7
    -mfpu=fpv5-d16
    -mfloat-abi=hard
    -mthumb
    -Wall
    -fdata-sections
    -ffunction-sections
)
```

Compile command that caused the error:

```
[build] /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -DSTM32F777xx -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -I<removed>  -g   -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -std=gnu11 -o <removed>.c.obj   -c <removed>.c
```

#### Research / What I've Tried

1. After reading I realize there's two (instruction sets? syntax parsers?) for armv7, and the processor can be in one of two modes for these (ARM and THUMB). But I don't fully understand this, and how it affects the parsing of handwritten assembly.
2. I suspected, because the processor is in thumb mode (-mthumb), it has something to do with my inline alias constraints? [Per documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) I tried switching between "+l", "+r", "+h" but it doesn't seem to change anything.
3. I tried using hardcoded registers "r3, r4, r5" instead of the inline aliases but that gave the same error.

Comment: `ldrex` and `strex` require an address as the last operand.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I changed `[lock] "+l"(*lock)` to `:[lock] "+l"(lock)`, but the error message remains unchanged.

Comment: Try `"+m"(*lock)` instead.

Comment: That was it, I had the wrong constraint. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note: If nobody writes that as a proper answer, feel free to answer this yourself...

Comment: @Jester: Can't find it in the manual right now, but does `ldrex` support all the addressing modes that the `m` constraint might use?

Comment: Thank's @hyde, I wasn't sure about procedure. I am allowed to mark it as solved 24 hours from now.

Comment: Yeah, answering in comments is generally not good anyway, so converting comments to answers is not stepping on anyones toes, almost by definitions of a comment and an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @jester's help, I realized I had the wrong constraint on the GCC-inline variable alias for the lock. It should have been "+m", specifying a memory address instead of a register.

<s>I was also de-referencing the address of the lock when I should have been leaving it as a pointer.</s>

I changed `[lock] "+l"(*lock)` to `[lock] "+m"(lock)` and it now builds.

Comment: `"+m"(lock)` forces the compiler to spill the pointer local variable from a register to memory, so the pointer itself can be in memory as an `"m"` operand.  It's not useful to atomically RMW your own local variable on the stack; no other thread can have a pointer to that anyway.  **You actually *do* want `[lock] "+m" (*lock)` to have the pointed-to memory as an RMW memory operand.**  If LDREX/STREX have limits on what addressing modes they support, you may need a more specific constraint than `"+m"`, but IDK if that's the case.